# Change form values using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, button

I have been asked to change text and style of a specific button within a form after a submit.

**JavaScript**

```
openWarningBox(
    "/URL", 
    [{
        'classNames':'button sec',
        'text':'Continue',
        'clickEvent': function() {
            $(document.forms.button).trigger('submit');
        }
    }]
);
```

**HTML**

```
<form name="button" onsubmit="location.href='/URL'; return false;"></form>
```

I am aware this is done in a weird/wrong way and if it was written properly it would not have been an issue, but is there some way for me to change that button's `classNames` and `text` after it is being submitted?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is what you are looking for but I used the DOM to change the button text and style you can also change the font that way. The DOM seems like a good option to accomplish this task.

```js
var btn = document.getElementById('btn')
btn.addEventListener('click', change)

function change(e){
  e.preventDefault()
  btn.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
  btn.style.border = 'blue';
  btn.style.colr = 'black';
  btn.style.borderRadius = '26px';
  btn.innerHTML = 'Submitted'
}
```

```css
button{
  background-color: #4CAF50; /* Green */
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <button type="submit" id='btn'>Submit</button>
</body>
</html>
```